# Cypher query returns Create Bug Exception

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am getting the following error when I try and get the results from a cyper query in Neo4JClient.

**Error:**

```
Neo4jClient encountered an exception while deserializing the response from the server. This is likely a bug in Neo4jClient.    
Please open an issue at https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issues/new    
To get a reply, and track your issue, ensure you are logged in on BitBucket before submitting.    
Include the full text of this exception, including this message, the stack trace, and all of the inner exception details.    

Include the full type definition of <>f__AnonymousType3`2[[Neo4jClient.Node`1[[IQS_ACL.Nodes.User, IQS ACL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Neo4jClient, Version=1.0.0.594, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Neo4jClient.Node`1[[IQS_ACL.Nodes.SecurityRelationshipObject, IQS ACL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Neo4jClient, Version=1.0.0.594, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].

Include this raw JSON, with any sensitive values replaced with non-sensitive equivalents:    

{    
  "columns" : [ "Node", "Rels" ],    
  "data" : [ [ {    
    "paged_traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",    
    "outgoing_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships/out",    
    "data" : {    
      "Name" : "root"    
    },    
    "traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/traverse/{returnType}",    
    "all_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",    
    "all_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships/all",    
    "property" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/properties/{key}",    
    "self" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690",    
    "properties" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/properties",    
    "outgoing_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",    
    "incoming_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships/in",    
    "incoming_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",    
    "extensions" : {    
    },    
    "create_relationship" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships"    
  }, {    
    "start" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690",    
    "data" : {    
      "W" : 3,    
      "R" : 3,    
      "ReadablePermissions" : "+R+W",    
      "X" : 1    
    },    
    "property" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/9351/properties/{key}",    
    "self" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/9351",    
    "properties" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/9351/properties",    
    "type" : "SECURITY",    
    "extensions" : {    
    },    
    "end" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7696"    
  } ], [ {    
    "paged_traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",    
    "outgoing_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships/out",    
    "data" : {    
      "Name" : "root"    
    },    
    "traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/traverse/{returnType}",    
    "all_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",    
    "all_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships/all",    
    "property" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/properties/{key}",    
    "self" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690",    
    "properties" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/properties",    
    "outgoing_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",    
    "incoming_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships/in",    
    "incoming_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",    
    "extensions" : {    
    },    
    "create_relationship" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690/relationships"    
  }, {    
    "start" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7690",
    "data" : {
      "W" : 3,
      "R" : 3,
      "ReadablePermissions" : "+R+W",
      "X" : 1
    },
    "property" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/9351/properties/{key}",
    "self" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/9351",
    "properties" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/9351/properties",
    "type" : "SECURITY",
    "extensions" : {
    },
    "end" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/7696"
  } ] ]}
```

**Code:**

```
var groups = clientConnection.Cypher
                .Start(new { n = "node(" + folderID + ")" })
                .Match("n<-[r:SECURITY]-x, x<-[v:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP*]-b where b.Name = '"+userName+"'")
                .ReturnDistinct((x, r) => new
                {
                    Node = x.As<Node<User>>(),
                    Rels = r.As<Node<SecurityRelationshipObject>>()
                });

var results = groups.Results;
It throws on the .Results();
```

If I run the query :

```
START n=node(7706) MATCH n<-[r:SECURITY]-x, x<-[v:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP*]-b where b.Name = 'user1' RETURN distinct x AS Node, r AS Rels;
```

in the console it returns:

```
Node[7700]{Name:"root"} | :SECURITY[9369] {ReadablePermissions:"+R+W",R:3,W:3,X:1} |
```

Bitbucket ticket: https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/153/cypher-query-returns-create-bug-exception

**Class definitions:**

```
public class User
{
    //CMIS Object Properties
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string BaseTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ObjectTypeId { get; set; }
    public IList<string> SecondaryObjectTypeIds { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string LastModificationDate { get; set; }
    public string ChangeToken { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroup
{
    //CMIS Object Properties
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string BaseTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ObjectTypeId { get; set; }
    public IList<string> SecondaryObjectTypeIds { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string LastModificationDate { get; set; }
    public string ChangeToken { get; set; }
}

public class RelationshipObject
{
    //CMIS Object Properties
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string BaseTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ObjectTypeId { get; set; }
    public Array SecondaryObjectTypeIds { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string LastModificationDate { get; set; }
    public string ChangeToken { get; set; }

    //RelationshipObject Properties
    public string sourceId { get; set; }
    public string targetId { get; set; }
}

public class SecurityRelationshipObject : RelationshipObject
{
    //CMIS Object Properties
    public IList<string> SecondaryObjectTypeIds { get; set; }
    public string ReadablePermissions { get; set; }
    public int R { get; set; }
    public int W { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
}
```

**Relationship definitions:**

```
public class RelationshipUserGroupToFolder: Relationship<SecurityRelationshipObject>, IRelationshipAllowingSourceNode<UserGroup>, IRelationshipAllowingTargetNode<FolderObject>
{
    string RelationshipName;

    public RelationshipUserGroupToFolder(string RelationshipName, NodeReference targetNode, SecurityRelationshipObject relationshipTypeObject)
        : base(targetNode, relationshipTypeObject)
    {
        this.RelationshipName = RelationshipName;
    }

    public override string RelationshipTypeKey
    {
        get { return RelationshipName; }
    }
}

public class RelationshipUserGroupToUserGroup : Relationship<RelationshipObject>, IRelationshipAllowingSourceNode<UserGroup>, IRelationshipAllowingTargetNode<UserGroup>
{
    string RelationshipName;

    public RelationshipUserGroupToUserGroup(string RelationshipName, NodeReference targetNode, RelationshipObject relationshipTypeObject)
        : base(targetNode, relationshipTypeObject)
    {
        this.RelationshipName = RelationshipName;
    }

    public override string RelationshipTypeKey
    {
        get { return RelationshipName; }
    }
}
```

There are some different types like RelationshipUserToFolder(security) or RelationshipUserToUseGroup(IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP)

Comment: Can you supply the class definitions of `User` and `SecurityRelationshipObject`, thanks!

Comment: Hi, I added it to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Great, and is `RelationshipObject` (base class for `SecurityRelationshipObject`) a relationship?

Comment: Yes, in fact it looks nearly exactly the same as SecurityRelationshipObject (the commented out parts at least is whats in it). I will edit it in quick.

Comment: OK, this will probably need some more info: 1. How is the `Security` relationship defined, 2. How is the `IsMemberOfGroup` relationship defined... As an aside note though - have you tried changing `Rels = r.As<Node<SecurityRelationshipObject>>()` to `Rels = r.As<RelationshipInstance<Security<SecurityRelationshipObject>>>()`

Comment: Tried that quickly, still doesn't work. The `var kUser = ... .Results` looks exactly the same as the groups one and that works for some reason. The difference between them is the groups one is a `clientConnection.CreateRelationship(root, new RelationshipUserGroupToFolder("SECURITY", rootFolder, new SecurityRelationshipObject { ReadablePermissions = "+W", R = 1, W = 3, X = 1 }));` vs `clientConnection.CreateRelationship(user1, new RelationshipUserToFolder("SECURITY", user1Home, new SecurityRelationshipObject { ReadablePermissions = "+R+W+X", R = 3, W = 3, X = 3 }));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain the problem is due to the `Rels = ...` bit of code, as I'm pretty certain you are attempting to cast a `Relationship` into a `Node` and Neo4j doesn't know how to do that. Also, JSON.NET (and by association, neo4jclient) doesn't know how to deserialize the `SecurityRelationshipObject` as it (and it's base class) have a property defined of type `Array` and `IList`, only `IEnumerable<>` collections can be deserialized.

To that end, the `.ReturnDistinct` should look like this:

```
/* Rest of query here */
.ReturnDistinct((x, r) => new
{
    Node = x.As<Node<User>>(),
    Rels = r.As<RelationshipInstance<SecurityRelationshipObject>>()
});
```

and the data objects should look like:

```
public class RelationshipObject {
    /* Other Properties */
    public IEnumerable<string> SecondaryObjectTypeIds { get; set }
}

public class SecurityRelationshipObject : RelationshipObject {
    /* Other Properties */
    public new IEnumerable<string> SecondaryObjectTypeIds { get;set; }
}
```

Though obviously, you don't need the property in the 'Security' version as it's already in the base class, *but* if you do have it, you should use the `new` keyword to indicate it is replacing the base class version.

If you've not got anything in those properties it will deserialize fine, which might explain why the `Node = x.As<Node<User>>()` is working ok, even though you have an `IList<>` there as well.

Below is a small program which when run (`Tester.Run()`) should output (`Chris has known jeff since yesterday`) - can you try this in a console app and see if it works for you? You should be able to copy / paste it in it's entirety..

---

```
using System;
using Neo4jClient;

public static class Tester
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost.:7474/db/data"));
        client.Connect();
        NodeReference<User> rootRef = AddData(client);

        var query = client.Cypher.Start(new {n = rootRef})
            .Match("n-[r:KNOWS]->other")
            .Return((other, r) => new
            {
                Other = other.As<Node<User>>(),
                Knows = r.As<RelationshipInstance<KnowsData>>()
            });

        var results = query.Results;

        foreach (var result in results)
            Console.WriteLine("Chris has known {0} since {1}", result.Other.Data.Name, result.Knows.Data.Since);
    }

    private static NodeReference<User> AddData(IGraphClient client)
    {
        var chris = new User {Name = "Chris"};
        var jeff = new User {Name = "Jeff"};

        NodeReference<User> chrisRef = client.Create(chris);
        NodeReference<User> jeffRef = client.Create(jeff);

        client.CreateRelationship(chrisRef, new Knows(jeffRef, new KnowsData {Since = "Yesterday"}));
        return chrisRef;
    }
}

public class User { public string Name { get; set; } }
public class KnowsData { public string Since { get; set; } }

public class Knows : Relationship<KnowsData>, IRelationshipAllowingSourceNode<User>, IRelationshipAllowingTargetNode<User>
{
    public Knows(NodeReference targetNode, KnowsData data) : base(targetNode, data) {}
    public override string RelationshipTypeKey { get { return "KNOWS"; } }
}
```

Comment: Ok so if I remove the rels part it works. I am just not sure how to change that now though. I tried a few things: `Rels = r.As<RelationshipInstance<SecurityRelationshipObject>>()` and your `r.As<RelationshipInstance<RelationshipUserGroupToFolder>>()` which throws a `Error 17 'IQS_ACL.Relationships.RelationshipUserGroupToFolder' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TData' in the generic type or method 'Neo4jClient.RelationshipInstance<TData>' C:\Users\Shaun\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\IQS ACL\IQS ACL\``

Comment: Agh! Totally forgot about the default constructor, please see the edit in my answer - sorry!

Comment: Awesome so that allows it in the cypher query but it does not seem to have the properties on it when I foreach over it (R,W,X etc)

Comment: Change the `RelationshipUserGroupToFolder` to `SecurityRelationshipObject` (I'll edit the answer)

Comment: That solves the properties issue (as in the code finds it) but it breaks with the same exception again now when I replace it with `SecurityRelationshipObject `

Comment: You're returning: `r.As<RelationshipInstance<SecurityRelationshipObject>>()` right?

Comment: Yes I am: `var groups = clientConnection.Cypher
                .Start(new { folder = "node(" + folderID + ")" })
                .Match("folder<-[r:SECURITY]-userGroup, userGroup<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP*]-user where user.Name = '" + userName + "'")
                .ReturnDistinct((userGroup, r) => new
                {
                    Node = userGroup.As<Node<User>>(),
                    Rels = r.As<RelationshipInstance<SecurityRelationshipObject>>()
                });`

Comment: I've added a 'test' program for you to see if it works, as far as I can tell, it's a close analogy for your situation, so I'm curious as to whether that works for you.

Comment: The test program works on my side (just added it to my dll and ran in console app)

Comment: I'm at a bit of a loss without the code to look at I'm afraid, as far as I can see, it should work. At a long shot - can you look at the `SecurityRelationshipObject` and `RelationshipObject`s in particular the `SecondaryObjectTypeIds` property, change it to: `public IEnumerable<string> SecondaryObjectTypeIds { get; set; }` in the base class and remove it from the `SecurityRelationshipObject` class (if you can)

Comment: Got it replicating in my code, it **is** the `Array` and `IList` definitions, you need to convert all `IList` and `Array` instances to `IEnumerable<>` (and it has to be the generic version).

Comment: Hi, yes it was the array. It sits in another employees dll and I didn't notice it at all. Thanks so much for the help even tho it just ended up being sloppy coding on our part. I also changed it to IList which seems to work (apparently it inherits from IEnumerable).

Comment: If you are ever in Cape Town, I owe you a beer.

Comment: Glad we got there in the end - I use `ICollection` everywhere, and spent quite a while trying to figure out why it wouldn't deserialize :)